# Recommended browser with Cisco products

Tags: cisco

What is the recommended browser to use with Cisco products ? I have menu problems with Cisco Unified Communication Manager 9 after IE upgraded to V11 (versions 9 and 10 were fine), and I have noticed same problem with IE11, Google Chrome and Firefox when accessing Cisco Secure ACS v5.4, but there are no browser issues with Cisco Network Analysis Module - Traffic Analyzer v5.1 and Cisco Unity.

[image: ACS report problem with IE11]

I just wonder if there is a browser that can work with all of the above no matter it's version.

Comment: The Screenshot here is from IE11 with Cisco Secure ACS 5.4 Monitoring tool.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [UCM v9.0 Release Notes](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/rel_notes/9_0_1/CUCM_BK_RF912712_00_cucm-release-notes-90_chapter_01.html#CUP0_RF_S1504705_00):

> *Supported browsers*
>
> Use the following Internet browsers to access the Unified Communications Manager and IM >and Presence Service interfaces:
>
> - Microsoft Windows: Microsoft Internet Explorer Version 6.0 or later or 
>                       Mozilla Firefox Version 3.x, 4.x, or 10.x
> - Mac: Safari 5.x or Mozilla Firefox Version 4.x or 10.x
>
> The following Internet browsers are officially supported to access the Enterprise License Manager interface:
>
> - Firefox: Version 8, 9, 10
> - Internet Explorer: Version 8, 9
> - Google Chrome: Version 15, 16, 17
> - Safari: Version 5.1

Comment: +1 for the documentation ref, but technically I think he's asking for a "single browser to work across all his Cisco platforms"

Comment: I admit the dream of the Golden Browser would be amazing but I don't see it ever happening, even across same vendor products. Browsers change to often. I guess the answer is, no. I keep ie9 and the latest stable ff. ie9 has a semi decent compatibility mode feature (press F12) that goes back to ie 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

For web management interfaces and the like, I have always found firefox to be the most compatible (least buggy) at interpreting HTML from various vendors and devices. However, I do not regularly use this browser personally, only professionally.

Comment: Sadly the OP includes Cisco ACS 5.4 in his list of products, and I can testify from personal experience that FF doesn't work with all of ACS 5.4's features (as much as I wish it did)

Comment: It's not the HTML that the browser has issues with 9 times out of 10, but the CSS/JavaScript/'extra' things embedded in the page that causes most browser compatibility issues.